# How to upload video to Drupal using Video module?

Tags: files

I've successfully installed the Video module and now there is no errors.

It's not clear to on Drupal website how I can start uploading videos though.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start uploading a video you have to create a new content type, and add a new field and use a field type of video. You can also choose a widget type of video upload.

Upon adding the field, on the next step you can add the extensions of the kind of video files you will like to upload